# Apple Watch app not run on different simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5

I have run the AppleWatch app on simulator in iPhone6s plus but i want to know how it can be run on iPhone4s simulator.

Comment: No problem , only i want to run on different simulator .But how please help me.

Comment: You can create new simulator from Product ->Destination -> Add Additional Simulators.

Comment: I have add additional simulator but after adding how can i run my applewatch app

Comment: Select the Watch scheme, and choose the new simulator.See my edited answer.

Comment: I have add simulator iPhone4s name as iPhone4s mySimulator but after adding the device not show like your image.

Comment: Have you added simulator for apple watch by selecting Device Type while creating new simulator???

Answer (score 1):

Apple Watch will require iPhone 5 or above. For more info see [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6525060?tstart=0).

**For running new simulator:**

[image]

For nice tutorial on Watch-kit see [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/117196/watchos-2-tutorial-part-1-getting-started).